# FFMPEG HLS video qualities scaling

Tags: ffmpeg

In my code I am trying to generate `m3u8` format of my single video in different qualities. My code is able to generate `m3u8` but without qualities its taking its original frame height and width instead of my defined one. I did my research over it but I am unable to accomplish the target right one. As I am new to `ffmpeg`. I don't know much about the commands and its fixes but I know I am doing something wrong in it

Here is my sample command list

```
//144p
ffmpeg -i test_video.mp4 -vf scale=256:144 -vcodec copy -acodec copy -vbsf h264_mp4toannexb -hls_time 2 -hls_list_size 999999999 out/144_vid.m3u8

//240p
ffmpeg -i test_video.mp4 -vf scale=426:240 -vcodec copy -acodec copy -vbsf h264_mp4toannexb -hls_time 2 -hls_list_size 999999999 out/240_vid.m3u8

//360p
ffmpeg -i test_video.mp4 -vf scale=640:360 -vcodec copy -acodec copy -vbsf h264_mp4toannexb -hls_time 2 -hls_list_size 999999999 out/360_vid.m3u8
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're copying the video stream, you can't apply filters to it.

You have to encode the video stream e.g.

```
ffmpeg -i test_video.mp4 -vf scale=256:144 -vcodec libx264 -crf 23 -acodec copy -vbsf h264_mp4toannexb -hls_time 2 -hls_list_size 999999999 out/144_vid.m3u8
```

`libx264` uses the x264 encoder. CRF 23 tells the encoder to maintain a constant quality. Lower values produce better quality but larger sizes.

Comment: @Gyan is there any way to get different qualities of m3u8 and then download in mp4 format?